# Getting a Response from a MySQL database when updating in VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, phpmyadmin, database-connection

I have a function similar to that below which updates my database with an SQL string passed into it.

Been using this for ages and all is fine, but it just occurred to me. Is it possible to receive a response from the database such `"X number of rows deleted/updated" as I get when making Delete/Update commands in phpMyAdmin?

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Function doUpdate(sql)
    Dim DBConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbConn").ConnectionString
    'this is getting the connection string from web.config file.

    Dim connection As MySqlConnection = MySqlConnection(DBConnection)
    Dim dataUpdate As MySqlCommand = MySqlCommand(sql, connection)

    Using connection
        connection.Open()
        Try
            dataUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ex.ToString() & "<hr/>" & InsertSql)
        End Try
    End Using

    ' // I WANT TO RETRIEVE A RESPONSE HERE
    Return DatabaseResponse

end function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows affected by modifications.

From MySQL reference material:

ExecuteNonQuery

Executes a SQL statement against the connection and returns the number of rows affected.

Returns: Number of rows affected

You can use ExecuteNonQuery to perform any type of database operation, however any resultsets returned will not be available. Any output parameters used in calling a stored procedure will be populated with data and can be retrieved after execution is complete. For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-executenonquery

Answer (score 0):

**MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery** returns the number of rows affected by the command.
So it is just a matter to read  the return value of ExecuteNonQuery.....

```
Dim rowAffected =  dataUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

DbCommand is the base class used by every specific implementation and [DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery is defined here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.executenonquery.aspx)

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1.